# Java - sending a message to WebSphere message broker and its altering my message

Tags: java, xml, websphere, messagebroker

So im sending a message to WebSphere and its successfully putting it on a queue. However I have having an issue getting it off another queue. But what I have noticed it when im sending me message using the line :

```
inputMessage.writeUTF(message);
```

with the message being:

```
basket/argos/1001?authToken=fgTSdfs&amp;trustToken=gdf43FsfSFefs33&amp;apiKey=ahjd9234imnmdfnwi&amp;sig=abcde&amp;currency=GBP
```

which is store in an xml file, it is appending a "n" to the front of the message. Can anyone tell me why? the code is below:

```
    MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

    // Config
    cf.setHostName(hostname);
    cf.setPort(portNumber);
    cf.setQueueManager(queueManager);
    cf.setChannel(channel);

    //MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
    //MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    //MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue(inputQueue);
    //MQQueue queue = (MQQueue)session.
    //MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
    //MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue);    


    MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(queueManager);
    System.out.println("Queue manager created");

    int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF |  
    MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT ;  
    System.out.println("MQ Options created");

    MQQueue mqInputQueue =  
        qMgr.accessQueue(inputQueue,  
                openOptions);

    System.out.println("Queue created");

    MQMessage inputMessage = new MQMessage();
    inputMessage.writeUTF(message);
    System.out.println("message created and sent");

    MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();  // accept the defaults,  
    // same as  
    // MQPMO_DEFAULT  
    // constant  
    System.out.println("Queue options created");

    // put the message on the queue  
    mqInputQueue.put(inputMessage,pmo);
    System.out.println("Message put on queue");
    mqInputQueue.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you reading the message after it is received? are using `readUTF` method? If you have used `writeUTF` while sending a message, then you must use `readUTF` method retrieve the message body after receive. The "n" could actually be the length of the XML message as, in UTF string, the first two bytes indicate the length of the string that follows.